# Is there a way to find the log of very large numbers?

Tags: numerical-methods, cryptography, information-theory, binary

I should like to evaluate $\log_2{256!}$ or other large numbers to find 'bits' of information. For example, I'd need three bits of information to represent the seven days of the week since $\lceil \log_2{7}\rceil = 3$, but my calculator returns an error for large numbers.

Comment: There's an important distinction between $\log_2 256!$ and $\lceil\log_2 256!\rceil$.  If you only need an approximation, then Stirling is the way to go.  If you need the actual value, then computers are more helpful (although there are refinements to Stirling).

Comment: Your title is poor English (despite the fact you rejected an improvement to it). "Is there a (simple) way"  would be better.

Comment: It was fine as it was originally. In any case, 'improvement' is an opinion and 'simple' would be presumptions. Let's stick to the mathematics.

Comment: Nope - "I should like" is fine. It's rather old-fashioned and perhaps more common in the UK ... e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19438/can-one-say-i-should-like-rather-than-i-would-like-is-the-former-grammatica

Comment: You say "or other large numbers" without saying what function produces those large numbers. If the numbers are the result of multiplications or exponentiations, then you should be able to apply the standard rules of logarithms. If you're characterizing large numbers by a function that uses something other than multiplication or exponentiation, say what the function is.  Note that there exist well-defined functions from integers to very large integers that we *cannot* determine the log of even approximately.

Comment: @RedBook1 “Is there are way” is not grammatical. You probably meant either “Is there a way” or “Is there any way”. (Many of the other changes that people tried making to your question seem unnecessary though.)

Comment: @ ShreevatsaR. Yes. You are right. That was my obvious oversight (I changed my mind and missed that) but I 'should' say the rest was fine.

Comment: One way to approximate it is by counting the number of primes less than that large number. If you're looking for a *reasonable* way to compute this, on the other hand...

Comment: What kind of calculator?  If it is using floating point representation, your day of week problem is hopeless.   If it has extended precision integer, your problem is trivial. Just do something like casting out nines in decimal arithmetic by casting out sevens in octal.

Comment: The logarithm problem is opposite: if you have floating point representation, the problem is trivial... but some numbers are so large that they cannot be represented in floating point.   If they are extended integers, you have more of a problem: count the number of bits, the do the rest of the math to get the fractional part of the base 2 log.   For what it's worth, my favorite calculator for serious number crunching is the WP-34.   HP has discontinued the platform, but you can get a really good emulator that runs on an iPhone.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If it's about factorials, you can use Stirling's approximation:

$$\ln(N!) \approx N\ln(N) - N$$

Due to the fact that

$$N! \approx \sqrt{2\pi N}\ N^N\ e^{-N}$$

**Error Bound**

Writing the "whole" Stirling series as

$$\ln(n!)\approx n\ln(n)−n+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi n)+\frac{1}{12n} −\frac{1}{360n^3}+\frac{1}{1260n^5}+\ldots $$

it is known that the error in truncating the series is always the opposite sign and at most the same magnitude as the first omitted term. Due to Robbins, we can bound:

$$\sqrt{2\pi }n^{n+1/2}e^{-n} e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}}  < n! < \sqrt{2\pi }n^{n+1/2} e^{−n} e^{1/12n}$$

**More on Stirling Series in Base $2$**

Let's develop the question of Stirling series when we have a base $2$ for example. The above approximation has to be read this way:

$$log_2(N!) \approx \log_2(\sqrt{2\pi N} N^N\ e^{-N})$$

Due to the fact that we have a non-natural log, it becomes

$$\log_2(N!) \approx \frac{1}{2}\log_2(2\pi N) + N\log_2(N) - N\log_2(e)$$

Hence one has to be very careful with the last term which is not $N$ anymore, but $N\log_2(e)$.

That being said one can proceed with the rest of Stirling series.

*See the comments for numerical results.*

**Beauty Report**

$$\color{red}{256\log_2(256) - 256\log_2(e) + \frac{1}{2}\log_2(2\pi\cdot 256) = 1683.9958175971615}$$

a very good accord with numerical evaluation (for example W. Mathematica) which gives $\log_2(256!) = 1683.9962872242145$.

Comment: It would be useful to have an error bound here.

Comment: How about $log_2{n!}$?

Comment: @SolomonUcko you can use the laws of logarithms: $$ \log_2 n! = { \ln n! \over \ln 2 } \approx { n \cdot \ln n - n \over \ln 2 } $$

Comment: @SolomonUcko As Tobia suggested, you can use the change of basis rule with ease.

Comment: @Tobia, thanks. I knew there was something like that, but I didn't remember the details. Also, can it convert from any base, or just base $e$?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes, it can convert from any base. The mnemonic rule is that the *base* is traditionally written *below* the word "log", so it goes on the *bottom* when you convert it to a fraction: $$ \log_{base} arg = { \log_x arg \over \log_x base } $$ and this is true for any $x$ (if the log exists, etc.)

Comment: So what's the error on $\log_2 256!$? How many correct digits does this method produce?

Comment: I mean, how many *provably* correct digits does this method produce (with your error bound)?

Answer (score 118):

By the laws of logarithms

$$ \log_2(256!) = \sum_{i=1}^{256} \log_2(i)$$

This is easily evaluated (albeit not on all calculators).

In Python:

```
>>> sum(math.log2(i) for i in range(1,257))
1683.9962872242136
```

Comment: This seems to me like a better answer given the scale of the numbers the OP asks about, as it will be more accurate.

Comment: As long as we’re optimizing, since lg 1 = 0, you could start with 2.

Comment: @DavisYoshida: Actually, because of floating-point issues, this is in general likely to be _less_ accurate than using Stirling's approximation to sufficiently many terms.

Comment: (Hmm computer experimentation doesn't seem to bear out my previous comment. Probably because of the division; need to look deeper… anyway, floating-point issues from adding up many terms is something to take into account, as note that for $n = 256$, the correct value is $1683.9962872242146…$ while the above from adding up the logs seems to give $1683.9962872242136$ which is an error at 12th decimal place. Probably not a big deal yet.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR As a rough rule of thumb, the error in adding up 256 floats of roughly the same magnitude should be around 256*(machine_epsilon) which would be (for 64 bit floats) $256*2^{-52} \approx 2.7 \times 10^{-14}$. Your calculation suggests that the error is *slightly* worse than that (probably since the numerical method to approximate logs has its own error). It is an interesting question of how large $N$ needs to be for round-off errors make the calculation worthless.

Comment: @Davislor True. Out of curiousity I ran `microbenchmark(sum(log2(1:256)), sum(log2(2:256)))` in R and see that on my machine you could save around 100 nanoseconds by starting with 2. Interestingly, `1+sum(log2(3:256))` does slightly *worse* than the simple `sum(log2(1:256))` (probably because it isn't fully vectorized).

Comment: The error of adding floating point numbers depends on the order and magnitude differenence. In this calculation it's added from smallest to biggest. If you turned the range around, then the result would be a lot more unprecise.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful That is why I stipulated that the numbers being added all be of roughly the same magnitude. `sum(math.log2(x) for x in range(256,0,-1))` agrees with the original calculation out to 11 decimal places, so I wouldn't characterize it as "a lot" more imprecise.

Comment: Indeed, logarithms grow slowly, so this should be pretty good to relatively large N.

Comment: Since you can group the terms in any way, `log (1*256) + log (2*255) + ... + log(127*129) + log(128)` is an alternative way to calculate this. This halves the number of terms, while the magnitude of terms now differs only by a factor of 64 instead of 256.

Comment: @MSalters That is a clever idea. It would be especially useful for larger $N$.

Comment: @Davislor yes, and replace the largest summand with 8.

Comment: On second thought, that odd `log(128)` term is a bit wrong. It should have been `log (1*256) + log (2*255) + ... + log(128*129)`. As noted, you can include or exclude the `1` term, so it's always possible to create pairs.

Comment: And the python `>>> sum(math.log2(i*(257-i)) for i in range(1,129))`
gives 1683.9962872242143, which indeed pushes the error back one digit.

Comment: @MSalters Nice. I suspect that your approach will be reasonable even for fairly large $N$.

Comment: John, that thing in @MSalters's comment is actually a cleverly disguised ["Gaussian"](https://nzmaths.co.nz/gauss-trick-staff-seminar) trick.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Well, not really - the terms here are not identical and need to be calculated individually. Note that I'm multiplying the sides of each pair, not adding them up. It's much closer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation

Comment: Why not `math.log2(math.factorial(256))`? (Or even more simply, `math.lgamma(257)/math.log(2)`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Fair question. OP's question was about how to calculate log factorials given computational limitations which preclude direct evaluation. Using the laws of logarithms is a natural answer to that question. The 1-line Python snippet was purely illustrative. Python itself has good support for big int computations, so in Python itself there isn't a strong motivation for doing this. In something like R (where `log2(factorial(256))` returns `Inf` and gives a warning message) it would be more motivated.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Although in R itself you would naturally use the `lgamma()` approach.

Comment: @JohnColeman What you listed is the magnitude of the *relative* error, not the absolute one. So the result obtained is well within the error range.

Comment: @DavisYoshida Actually, the initial comment I made, which I later thought was wrong, was actually correct :-) Compared to writing `sum(math.log2(i) for i in range(1,257))`, using Stirling's approximation and writing `(n*math.log2(n) - n/math.log(2) + math.log2(n*math.pi*2)/2 + 1/(n*12*math.log(2)) - 1/(n**3*360*math.log(2)))` (with `n = 256`) gives a number closer to the correct value.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR at the time of my comment, I believe only the first two terms of the Stirling series were in the accepted answer, so at the time I believe I was correct

Comment: Expected error grows as sqrt(n), not n. So for 256 terms, it should be 64*machine_epsilon.

Comment: I think that internally, the math module implements log2(x) as log(x)/log(2), so if you do `sum([math.log(i)+math.log(257-i) for i in range(1,129)])/math.log(2)`, you only have to do the log(2) division once, giving a very small improvement to accuracy and speed. And `sum([math.log(i)+math.log(257-i) for i in range(1,129)])/math.log(2)` seems to be faster than `sum(math.log(i)+math.log(257-i) for i in range(1,129))/math.log(2)`.

Comment: @Acccumulation: `log2` is easy for binary computers. The integral part is counting bits, and the fractional part is easy with $log(x)=1/16 log(x^16)$

Comment: @MSalters Your formatting could use some work. I assume you mean (1/16)(log(x^16)). This requires four multiplication operations, and gives you four bits. That isn't very precise, or efficient.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Squaring is cheaper than multiplication, as it only take one argument. It can even be done in-place here, which means you need only one CPU register. As for precision, you're likely to hit representation limits first. 24 fractional bits is all you need for a single-precision IEEE754 float.

Comment: @Acccumulation: You can see the implementation of `math.log2` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cb4661707818cfd92556e7fdf9068a993577002/Modules/mathmodule.c#L755-L769). It's implemented in a way that's usually more accurate than doing `log(x)/log(2)`.

Answer (score 12):

In Emacs, `C-x * * 256 ! 2 B N` will readily deliver
1683.99628722
and of course you are free to increase the precision of your calculation.  Stuff definitely is fast enough that there isn't much incentive for designing a solution outside of your editor.

Comment: Truly, Emacs is the only software you ever need.

Comment: I feel editor envy. Can that not be done with vim??

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Sure, it could be done with Vim, someone would just have to re-implement [Emacs Calc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html), which is a pretty large piece of software by itself, in Vim. I suspect it was easier to implement in Emacs Lisp than it would be in Vimscript, though. :-)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider you can run commands or other programs, like `bc`, from inside vi (and I suppose Vim). For example: `:r ! echo "( l(8*a(1))/2 +  (256+1/2)*(l(256)-1) + 1/2 ) / l(2)" | bc -l` will calculate and bring back into the editor: `1683.99581759716152712952`. Who needs emacs ...

Comment: Amazing. I just spent 5 minutes admiring how this _just works_ in Emacs, follwed by about 10 minutes figuring out how to _close the calculator window again_, as it had meddled with my accustomed Vim bindings (Evil) without which I'm completely lost in Emacs...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Sure, if Vim is compiled with the +python option you can do it with ":from math import *" followed by ":py print log(factorial(256))/log(2)" Much more readable than Emacs :P

Answer (score 11):

Just a comment:

Of course, there are many calculators that can handle $\log_2 256!$ and much "worse" expressions directly. For example [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), if you type

```
log(256!)/log(2)
```

you will get a result like:

```
%1 = 1683.9962872242146194061476793149931595
```

(the number of digits can be configured with the *default* called `realprecision`).

If you want an exact integer logarithm, you can also use `logint(256!, 2)` which will give you `1683`.

Typing `256!` alone will give you the full 507-digit decimal expansion of this integer.

If PARI/GP is allowed to use memory (set `parisizemax` default), it will also immediately say that `logint(654321!, 2)` is `11697270`.

---

As noted in comment, with reference to answer by Charles, if you want to work with floating-point operations (and not huge exact integers), you can use function `lngamma` which is equal to $\log\circ\Gamma$ for *positive real* arguments. Remember that compared to factorial, the Gamma function is shifted by one. So
$$\log_2 n! = \frac{\log n!}{\log 2} = \frac{\log \Gamma(n+1)}{\log 2}$$
and you can type `lngamma(654321 + 1)/log(2)` in PARI/GP and everything will be floating point operations. This will work for astronomical values of $n$, for example `lngamma(3.14e1000)` is fine ($\log\Gamma(3.14\cdot 10^{1000})$).

Comment: The excellent PARI/gp implements too the much faster lngamma function (proposed by Charles) and lngamma(N+1)/log(2)  should reduce the possibility of overflows for $N\gg 1$.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, your example is small enough to be computed directly with many systems. I should mention that many systems implement
$$
\log\Gamma(x)
$$
usually with names like `lngamma` or `lgamma`. You can then compute
$$
\log_2(256!)=\frac{\log\Gamma(257)}{\log 2}
$$
with minimal difficulty (and without leaving double precision).

In general some care is needed to work with the gamma function (branch cuts and numerical analysis), but in your case as long as you stick to factorials of numbers from 1 to 10<sup>305</sup> or so you should be just fine with 64-bit `double`s.

Comment: Although only the positive integers are relevant for the question it should be noted that $\log(\Gamma(x)) \not= \log\Gamma(x)$ in several common multiprecision programs. (For details see e.g.: D. E. G. Hare's "Computing the Principal Branch of log-Gamma". ) This might also be the case for "normal" (double precision) calculators if they support complex numbers, so a bit of caution is advised. For example the difference between `abs(lngamma(-3.4)) ~ 12.6163` and `abs(log(gamma(-3.4))) ~ 1.1212` can cause some severe headaches if hidden deeply in a large formula.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Yes, good advice for the general case. When working with positive integers it should not matter. I'll edit in some general remarks.

Answer (score 4):

If the number is not a factorial but rather any large number then a cutest way would be to consider the fundamental theorem of number theory.

says for any integer $n$ we have  $$n =\prod p_i^{a_i}$$ where p_i's are prime numbers. then by the law of log you get $$\log n= \sum a_i\log p_i.  $$

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a question about evaluating to get a result rather than understanding the method behind that result, the *online computational knowledge engine* [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(256!)) is always an option. A truly fantastic resource that gives the result to great accuracy almost instantly without the need for programming or even mathematical experience

[image]

Comment: If you're using Alpha (or *Mathematica* for that matter), you can use `LogGamma[256 + 1]/Log[2]` instead of separately computing the factorial before taking the logarithm.